# Can't set UIProgressView lower than 0.15

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

I have a progress view and can't seem to set it's progress lower than 0.15. If I do, it still appears as it's progress is at 0.15. After the progress grows beyond this value, everything works OK.

The view inspector shows the two image views for the tracking and progress tint colors, but from the start (when progress should be 0), the one for the tracking color has a width of 66 and it can't seem to go lower than this. I saw an earlier post (from 2013) that said to just use a `UISlider` instead. This doesn't seem to be an elegant solution.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: What is the width of your `UIProgressView`? I don't have any issues with incrementing the progress bar from 0.0 by 0.01 increments.

Comment: It's the width of the entire screen...

Comment: OK - and what is that width (screens have different sizes)?

Comment: What width? the 66 one? That's for the tracking tint color imageview used internally by the progressView ..

Comment: When your "tracking color image" width is 66 --- ***what is the width of the progress bar itself?***

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Swift, so try running this in a Playground page - it starts the ProgressView at 0.0 and increments the .progress by 0.01 on each button tap: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/75ef8250a03305d695c353ce15e32f08

Comment: I updated that gist to show a `UIProgressView` with a width of `100`, so each button tap will increase the `.progress` value by `1`. The first 4 taps will result in a "progress tint width" of 4, after which it will expand by only 1-pt each time. In other words, setting `.progress` to 0.07 results in a tint-width of 7... https://gist.github.com/DonMag/75ef8250a03305d695c353ce15e32f08